# .htaccess redirect dynamic URL (with numeric ID) to remove "track" from the end

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

It seems to be easy, but I can't figure out how to solve it, nothing worked for me. I have a dynamic URL like: `http://www.example.com/user/46/track` and I want to redirect from that URL to `http://www.example.com/user/46/`. The number `46` is a user ID so it's dynamic.

I have already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/track(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^/user/*(.*)/(\?.*)?$ /user/*$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can somebody help me with this solution? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is "track" fixed? Or is that _dynamic_ also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/track(.*)$ $1
> ```

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against never *starts with a slash*, since the directory-prefix - that notably *ends with a slash* - is first removed. However, unless this directive was physically located in a `.htaccess` file at `/user/46/.htaccess` then this would never match anyway.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/user/*(.*)/(\?.*)?$ /user/*$1$2 [R=301,L]
> ```

This is closer, but again, you have the slash-prefix problem as mentioned above. You also seem to be trying to match the query string and passing this through to the target URL? The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string - so this will never capture anything. Besides, you don't actually need to do anything with the query string if you want this passed through to the target URL - since this is the default behaviour. You also appear to have a stray `*` in both the *pattern* and *substitution* arguments? This will likely break the target URL.

---

Try something like the following instead. This will need to go near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, before any other rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/track$ /user/$1/ [R=302,L]
```

The above assumes that "track" is fixed, so specifically matches a URL of the form `/user/46/track`, where `46` can be any number of digits. With regex it is better to be as specific as possible, so if the ID can only consist of digits then only match digits etc.

If you simply wanted to remove anything after `/user/46/` then you could change the above directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/. /user/$1/ [R=302,L]
```

The trailing dot on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches any character, so ensures that there is *something* that follows `/user/46/` (for example). It is this "something" that is being removed.

Any query string on the original request is passed through unaltered.

If this is intended to be a permanent (301) redirect then only change the above `302` when you have tested that this is working OK, to avoid any caching issues messing with your testing. As always, clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: And if you can instead put directives in Apache main configuration instead of `.htaccess`, then `RewriteRule` directives are far simpler to write since there you really deal with the complete URL.